MS Word transparent Text Box background nonetheless visible in print & pdf
In a Word 2019 document, there are Text Boxes that have transparent backgrounds. Behind them (ZOrder) are shapes (rectangles). It looks okay on screen. For some reason though the text boxes visibly alter the color of the rectangles in print. I've attached a photo. (On the left: unwanted artifacts. On the right: correct printout.)


I printed the document into pdf, and the rectangles in the background behind the text were even more mangled and pixelated, as opposed to areas without text. This gave me the clue that Word might be rasterizing parts of the shapes. I tried fiddling with Word's image quality settings but to no avail.
The workaround (not really a solution) is that I discovered it happens only when the text box is in a group. Ungrouping it 'solved' the issue. Basically prepare a second, printable version of the document with all groups removed.
